# Count consecutive instances of a certain value

Tags: r, dplyr

What would be the best dplyr-esque way to answer this question of `dat`:

How many consecutive times by `grp` has `x` been 1 (assuming some internal order to `dat`)?

EDIT: assume that these ordered and everything should be based on the "last" value in the `grp`. So that is when `order` is 4.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(
  order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  x = c(1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1),
  grp = c(rep("gr1", 4), rep("grp2", 4), rep("grp3", 4))
)
dat
#>    order   x  grp
#> 1      1 1.0  gr1
#> 2      2 1.0  gr1
#> 3      3 1.0  gr1
#> 4      4 0.5  gr1
#> 5      1 1.0 grp2
#> 6      2 1.0 grp2
#> 7      3 1.0 grp2
#> 8      4 1.0 grp2
#> 9      1 1.0 grp3
#> 10     2 0.5 grp3
#> 11     3 0.5 grp3
#> 12     4 1.0 grp3
```

Desired output:

```r
#>   x  grp
#> 1 0 grp1
#> 2 4 grp2
#> 3 1 grp3
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do (e.g., I'm not sure why grp1 is 0 in your desired output), but run length encoding (the `rle()` function in R) might be useful.

Comment: grp1 is 0 because it has had 0 consecutive instances of being 1. Definitely `rle()` is probably the answer but I just can't grok how.

Comment: Doesn't grp1 have 3 consecutive instances of being 1.0?

Comment: oops wasn't clear in the question: "assuming some internal order to dat" meaning that this was in order so that the last value is what I am interested in.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question perfectly either, but here is a potential solution in `data.table`. Does this give what you want on another example? `library(data.table)` `setDT(dat)` `dat[, fifelse(x[.N] == 1.0, max(rle(x)$lengths[which(rle(x)$values == 1.0)]), 0), by = grp]`

Comment: yes yes it does! I didn't want a data.table solution but maybe we can adapt to dplyr or base R

Comment: This works: `dat %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  group_modify(~{
    if (.x$x[.x$order == max(.x$order)] == 1) {
      dat <- max(rle(.x$x)$lengths[which(rle(.x$x)$values == 1.0)])
    } else {
      dat <- 0
    }
    data.frame(consec = dat)
  })`

Comment: If that code works, you should add it as an answer and then mark it as accepted. To the person who supplied an answer but then deleted it when the question changed: your code was exactly what I was looking for, but I didn't manage to copy it before you deleted it!

Comment: alternatively you could add it? I just used your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(x = last(rle(x == 1)$lengths) *(last(x) == 1)), grp]
      grp     x
   <char> <int>
1:   grp1     0
2:   grp2     4
3:   grp3     1
```

Comment: +1, much better to do `rle(x == 1)$lengths` than the convoluted `rle(x)$lengths[which(rle(x)$values == 1.0)]`. For OP, to do this in `dplyr`: `dat %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(x = last(rle(x == 1)$lengths) *(last(x) == 1))`.